# Measure execution speed inside of Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, execution-time

I am working on developing a Shiny app.

I am interested in clocking the time it takes to execute certain chunks of code (such as a `ggplot`, etc).

For some reason it appears that using the usual clocking methods don't work within reactive calls, for example:

```
output$R1_C1 <- renderPlot({

beginning <- Sys.time()

<lots of code here> 

end <- Sys.time()
print(end - beginning)
```

R complains and gives me

```
Error in (structure(function (input, output)  : 
  object 'beginning' not found
```

Has anyone found a successful way to time execution speed inside of reactive calls in Shiny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on my system:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      beginning <- Sys.time()
      h <- hist(runif(input$n)) 
      end <- Sys.time()
      print(end - beginning)
      h
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 2):

In a similar way, you can use the `tictoc` package as shown below. The reason I prefer this over the base R solution is because you can easily use multiple tic/toc tags to measure sub-routines within either a reactive or a rendering expression.

```
library(shiny)
library(tictoc)

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ),
server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    tic("execution time - Histogram")
    hist(runif(input$n)) 
    toc()

    tic("execution time - Print")
    print("this is a second task within 'renderPlot' ")
    toc()
  })
 }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `profvis` package might be useful. Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(profvis)

profvis({

  sApp <- shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(
      numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100, min = 1, max = 200),
      plotOutput('plot')
    ),

    server = function(input, output) {

      dfTable <- reactive({
        as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10 * input$n, mean = 5), ncol = input$n))
      })

      vMeans <- reactive({
        apply(dfTable(), 2, mean)
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(vMeans())
      })
    }
  )

  runApp(sApp)
})
```