# Time shiny rendering speed

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

If I understand correctly, how R Shiny works is,

1. computation happens in R, Shiny does the "translation" for generating html/javascript
2. computation happens in Browser, html/javascript gets rendered by browser

We can do profiling for Shiny R side runtime with profvis or more easily (Sys.time). But many times, the rendering slowdown on the browser side. Is there a way to access browser rendering speed from R?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measure execution speed inside of Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664411/measure-execution-speed-inside-of-shiny)